# Sharepoint workflow is automattically canceling?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

We are having our Sharepoint workflow automattically canceling??  Every once in awhile this would happened. This is the 3rd time out of 20 infopath forms. I am not sure what is causing this and am not sure how to troubleshoot this eiether.  It doesnt happend when the workflow starts but rather in the middle of the process which is a lenghty workflow with several steps.

no messages I can see. It just sAYS workflow is canceled.  I even tried to run a workflow report and it says report has no data.

I do not see anything in the server logs ?????

now we discovered 2 more workflows that were mysteriously canceled in a another library.  it seems sporadic.

these are web forms

I found this

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496152

but mine are not canceling immediately and its only on a hand full not all

I think I am going to recreate the workflows. I think something could have got broken in the workflow schema b/c I tried to reuse a list workflow with a newly created form library. It seemed to work for awhile though.

I sort of opened the xml file and changed the list ID and imported it into the worklfow folder with SPDes

I notice they are canceling in the middle of the parrallel Block where multiple tasks (collect data from a user) are running at the same time on all 6 canceled workflows

Any experiences out there? Thanks

Comment: If this is SharePoint 2007 I would check if any user is trying to approve stuff with the System Account, and if any groups are involved you could check them for a "Who can view this group" to "Everyone", those are both old bugs, but you haven't provided any version info.

Comment: This would be better asked on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

It could be worth checking what is written in ULS logs (c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\logs). You will find quite a lot of information there, search for the exact hour/minute/second when it happened.

Comment: this is actually sp 2010 so it would be the 14 hive. I know abonut the uls logs. I have searched with no luck but will look again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a column who’s value would change as soon as the workflow condition was met, thus cancelling itself. So check to make sure your columns are not automatically updated based on another column at the same time the workflow is running.